# Mysql Explain Select "operation", "key_len" and "ref"

Tags: mysql, sql, select, innodb, explain

I have two identical InnoDB tables

Second table was created with

```
CREATE TABLE second LIKE first;
INSERT INTO second SELECT * FROM first;
```

Okay.

But when I'm trying to EXPLAIN SELECT it shows me this for first table:

```
type=ref, key_len=4, ref=const
```

for second:

```
type=range, key_len=16, ref=NULL
```

all other values are identical.

Need to say, that SELECT from second table works much faster than SELECT from first canonical table.

The indices are all the same in first and second tables.

If you need more details I can give it.

UPD: the first table has got Triggers on it, but it will fire only when insert/update will run.

UPD2: no one table uses Memory access methods

Comment: Try optimizing the tables and see if the explain is the same.

Comment: We'll need to see the definitions of the two tables. Get them using `SHOW CREATE TABLE first` etc.  We'll also need to see the query.  It looks like your newly created table has an appropriate index for a range-scan query (which can be very efficient). Does the first table use the `MEMORY` access method?

Comment: can't show create table (NDA you know)
extra shows "Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort" on both tables

so I want to know, how can I recalculate first table, that it will use "range" operation instead of "ref" for example

Comment: @Barmar, OPTIMIZE TABLE will just recreate table 'cause InnoDB doesn't support optimizing. So… I done this already, just with creation of "second" and filling it with data from "first"
my point is to "do something" that will treat old table as new

Comment: Do `show create table` and post it with the columns renamed, to avoid NDA problems.

Answer (score -1):

FORCE KEY was resolved my problem
MySQL 5.5 Percona

Comment: That's one sad solution

Comment: no debate, but it was something that helped me out with this particular issue :) 4.5 years ago